# Access keys for client side api

Tags: api, client-side

GI am trying to use a client side utility to download/manage files from Google cloud storage.  It (CloudBerry) requires the access and secret keys. How do I find those keys?

Answer (score 0):

It strictly depends on whether you want to create:

1. a general purpose tool, allowing different users to download/manage their Google Drive files (in particular, a web-based tool) - goto http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zJVCKvXtHtE
2. an automated tool with the usage restricted to you / your server only, that is going to deal with a specific Google account - goto http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK14bfd6qhs